# Would an app, featuring only a Webview component, get approved for the AppStore?

Tags: ios-appstore

I am not a mobile app developer, but we do feature responsive design in our website which works very well across all mobile browsers.

So if I were to make an app that only contains a fullscreen WebView component that loads the website, would that app be approved to get on the Appstore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apps which are just web views are specifically against the App Review Guidelines:

> **2.12** Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected

<sup>Source: [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)</sup>

Comment: "May be" rejected? Are there situations where they get approved? Do you know any examples or reasons why some get approved?

Comment: @ImNotMike One of my first apps was just a website as I wanted to look in to the process of app submission rather than the development process, and despite using JS touch events, AJAX loading, etc, it got rejected for this very reason. It was a I spent a long time integrating it more, using iCloud key store, Passbook, etc, and it got approved. The app's not currently on the App Store as I took it down; it was only meant to be a test.

Comment: So it's kind of okay to do that, but it just isn't allowed to only be the website and nothing else. In your opinion, would they approve it if i implemented some kind of background checker for new articles, which would push a notification when a new article has been published? That would be pretty useful and a "good excuse" to download the app as opposed to only bookmarking the website.

Comment: @ImNotMike That seems reasonable. Of course, different reviewers might have different opinions, so one reviewer might reject it and another approve it.

Answer (score -4):

In my experience....no, would not get approved.

Comment: What does this answer contribute that George's answer does not?